# How does prototype work for onSubmit:function()?

Tags: javascript, css, onsubmit

I was working on  [Co-drops Minimal Form Interface.](https://github.com/codrops/MinimalForm) I couldn't understand this code snippet in stepsForm.js. (Line 50)

```
stepsForm.prototype.options = {
        onSubmit : function() { return true; }
    };
```

I am new to JS, and wouldn't mind an explanation of the entire code in stepsForm if anyone has the time to do so. But, for the time being, an explanation for the above can do wonders for me. I know what a prototype is, but the onSubmit part is going over my head. I read on another question that this is to prevent refresh, but I feel that is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library exposes `options` property that you may/can use to pass your own overriding values.This one in particular, exposes `onSubmit`.

For any html `form` an `onSubmit` is called when the submit action is invoked by another function or by click.

In the library the default `onSubmit` is returning true, meaning just execute the action. This can be overriden with you custom function like this...

```
<script>
    var FORM_ELEMENT = document.getElementById( 'myForm' )
    new stepsForm(FORM_ELEMENT, {
        onSubmit :
        function (FORM_ELEMENT) {
            alert('You are about to submit the form ');
            //manipulate your form or do any preprocess work... 

            return true;

        });
</script>
```

Within the library the `_submit` (line 196 stepForm.js) is called which inturn calls the `onSubmit`. This time, instead of the default, it will execute the one we added above.

```
stepsForm.prototype._submit = function() {
    this.options.onSubmit(this.el);
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any point in returning a specific value though, it's ignored.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Understood it within no time.

Comment: @RobG  if you are referring to `return true` in the end of onsubmit, isn't it actually confirming the onSubmit to go ahead and complete else fail/stop when false. Am I wrong in saying that ?

Comment: The returned value isn't used at all. When the transition ends, *self._submit()* is called which calls *this.options.onSubmit( this.el )* which just does *return false*. None of the return values are used for anything.